# JourneyBuilderContactService.Validate error. when I try to activate a journey even when I get no errors when I Validate the journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have a journey which runs when a Data extension is populated via automation.

I have validated the journey and get no errors, but when I test the journey with Contacts in the journey I get an error: We encountered an error running the test, please try again.

When I attempt to activate the journey I get the error:
JourneyBuilderContactService.Validate error.

The emails from the journey have several personalisations (via ampscript) however when I test the emails I get no errors and with test data from the DE they look fine, have no errors and I am able to test send them to myself.

I have complied with CanSpam - I have the registered address entered on the email and the profile centre

Comment: Did you a test send with the data from your entry DE? Sometimes, we use a test DE and the error might be due to some filed missing in your entry DE that is being using utilized in your ampscript

Answer (score 0):

Could be related to Contact Builder / Designer issue, you might have removed the Entry Data Extension from the attribute group or deleted a filter attributes.

Verify that you have GOAL/EXIT criteria, decision splits rules, defined correctly, just check the path makes sure it's not broken.

If this isn't solving you issue, better create a new journey.